# Converting mysql Connection

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database connection I'm working on for an old site I'm converting, and I'm trying to update this `mysqli_select_db` string, but I cant figure out what to put as the variable for the database name now. It USED to be `$mysqldb` but now that I've changed it to pull from the `config.ini` file, I dont have a specific variable anymore... or do I? Thanks in advance! I tried googling other answers, but this one is sort of specific.

```
<?php
$config = parse_ini_file('config.ini'); 
$conn = mysqli_connect($config['mysqlhost'], $config['mysqluser'], $config['mysqlpwd'], $config['mysqldb']) or die(mysqli_connect_error()); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, $mysqldb) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
?>
```

Comment: Looks good. What is the issue? Is database connection pass?

Comment: You're already specifying the database in the call to `mysqli_connect()`. You don't need to call `mysqli_select_db()` as well.

Comment: It looks like the variable is `$config['mysqldb']`.

Comment: You shouldn't call `mysqli_connect_error()` for errors from functions other than `mysqli_connect()`. In other cases you should call `mysqli_error($conn)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `mysqli_select_db` when you choose database in `mysqli_connect` function.

But if you want do this:

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $config['mysqldb']);
```

Answer (score 0):

this really depends on your config.ini file. As described at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php, `parse_ini_file` converts your ini configuration into an associative array. Your config.ini might look like so:

```
mysqlhost=localhost
mysqluser=root
mysqlpwd=secret
mysqldb=database_name
```

If it does, you can use your code as is, except for the `mysqli_select_db` call, which you have implicitly used in `mysqli_connect`.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use mysqli_select_db... 
Since you have already specify the db in mysqli_connect